# unset php post ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script like a shopping cart.
When a user click on save it fills the array post with the save value, it reload the php script then it prints "remove".
Then after that when the user click on remove, it prints "remove" because there is still the value save in the array post.
Is there an error with that code ?

```
    if($_POST['statut']=='save'){
    echo "remove";
    unset($_POST['statut']);
}
    if($_POST['statut']=='remove') {
    echo "save";
    unset($_POST['statut']);    
}
```

the save function:

```
$.post(host+"button-save.php", {"statut":"save"},  function(result) {$('#button-save').html(result);});
```

the remove function

```
  $.post(host+"button-save.php", {"statut":"remove"},  function(result) {$('#button-save').html(result);});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `"button": key` be `"button": keybdd` ? Or change `$('#button-save'+keybdd+'')` to `$('#button-save'+key+'')` for the *remove* function ?

Comment: Why are you doing both `$.post` *and* `.load`?  They both do the same thing (except one puts the result into an element).

Comment: That code stills prints out "remove" on the screen because the value in the post array is still "save" i saw that in my browser's console.

Comment: I think i found out, there were twice action save and remove in the div so i empty the div before adding the new html.